# Showing $b^2 \notin \langle a \rangle$ for $V_{8n}=\langle a,b:a^{2n}=e, b^4 = e, ba=a^{-1}b^{-1},b^{-1}a=a^{-1}b\rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

For $n \in \mathbb N$, finite group $V_{8n}$  is
$$ V_{8n} = \langle a, b  : a^{2n} = e, b^4 =e, ba = a^{-1}b^{-1}, b^{-1}a = a^{-1}b \rangle. $$

This group is defined in [this paper](https://tus.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=repository_action_common_download&item_id=1229&item_no=1&attribute_id=22&file_no=1)  for all $n \in  \mathbb N.$

> I want to prove that $b^2 \notin \langle a \rangle$.

If possible,   let $b^2  \in \langle a \rangle$. Then $b^2 = a^t$ for some $t$. I observe that the possibility of $t$ is $n$. Since $ba = a^{2n -1}b^3$ so that by mathematical induction on $i$, we get
$$ ba^i = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
a^{2n -i}b & \mbox{if $i$ is even };\\
a^{2n - i}b^3& \mbox{if $i$ is odd}\end{array} \right.$$

If $n$ is odd, then   $b^3 = ba^n =  a^n b^3$ implies $a^n = e$; a contradiction. I am stuck here if $n$ is even.  I would be thankful for your kind help.

Comment: Can you explain your inductive argument a bit more? Also how do you have $ba = a^{2n-1} b^3$. Are you missing a relation that $b^4 = e$?

Comment: I can't find the definition in the paper.

Comment: From the second & third relations of the presentation, we have $(ba)^2=e$ and $ba=b^2a^{-1}b$, so the presentation is $$\langle a, b\mid a^{2n}=(b^2a^{-1}b)^2\stackrel{(E)}{=}e, b^{-1}a=a^{-1}b\rangle.$$ If $b^2\in\langle a\rangle$, then $b^2$ commutes with $a$, so $(E)$ and the third relation give $$b^2\cdot a^{-1}\cdot b^3\cdot (b^{-1}a)=e,$$ *i.e.*, $b^4=e$, @desiigner.

Comment: From $b^2=a^t$ and $b^4=e$, we have $a^{2t}=a^{2n}=e$, so either $$n\mid t$$ or $$t\mid n.$$

Comment: It might help to note that the third relation gives $(a^{-1}b)^{-1}=a^{-1}b$, *i.e.*, $$(a^{-1}b)^2=e.$$ So the presentation can be written with all its relators being proper powers. That is to say that another presentation of $V_{8n}$ is $$\langle a,b\mid a^{2n}, (ba)^2, (a^{-1}b)^2\rangle.$$

Comment: The group defined by that presentation is not finite. But it is true that $b^2 \not\in \langle a \rangle$. That follows from the fact that it has the dihedral group of order $4n$ as a quotient

Comment: @Shaun: Thanks for editing and valuable comments. Now, it is more readable.

Comment: @Shaun:  Now you can see the definition see on page no. 6.

Comment: You have missed out the relation $b^4=1$, whihc is necessary to make the group finite.

Comment: If you take the quotient obtained by adding the extra relation $b^2=e$, then you get the dihedral group of order $4n$. Since $b^2 \ne a^n$ in that quotient, then $b^2 \ne a^n$ in $V_{8n}$. But it seems to me that you still need to prove that $b^2 \ne 1$ in $V_{8n}$.

Comment: @ Derk: You are right, I missed that $b^4 = e$

Comment: The paper claims that the group $V_{8n}$ has order $8n$. If this is true then the result you are after holds: every element can be written in the form $a^ib^j$, and and there are at most $8n$ such forms ($2n$ choices for $i$ and $4$ choices for $j$). As the group has order $8n$ these forms uniquely define the elements and the result follows. (You probably want to verify that the group does have order $8n$...)

Comment: @User1729-  This is fine what you have written. I have also observed this thing and I know that $o(V_{8n}) = 8n$  if and only if $b^2 \notin \langle a \rangle$. Can I prove $b^2 \notin \langle a \rangle$ from the group presentation?

Comment: I'm glad you were trying to prove that the order of the group is as the paper claims it is. I think it is poor form on the side of the authors to not prove this claim, and its always helpful to verify these kinds of claims when reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the relations $bab=a^{-1}$ and $ba^{-1}b = a$, we get $b^2ab^2 = a$, and since $b^4=1$, this implies $b^{-2}ab^2 = a$, so $b^2 \in C_G(a)$. Since clearly $b^2 \in C_G(b)$, this gives $b^2 \in Z(V_{8n})$.

Now, the calculation in user1729's answer shows that $V_{8n}/\langle b^2 \rangle$ is isomorphic to the fihedral group of order $4n$. Since $b^4=1$, this proves that $|V_{8n}| \le 8n$ and $|V_{8n}| \ge 4n$. But to prove that $b^2 \not\in \langle a \rangle$, we still have to prove that $b^2 \ne 1$, which would show that $|V_{8n}| = 8n$.

To prove that, we follow the standard procedure of contructing a group $\langle a,b \rangle$ of order $8n$ in which $a$ and $b$ satisfy the relations of $V_{8n}$.

Start with the group $H = \langle a,c \mid a^{2n}=c^2=1, ac=ca \rangle \cong C_{2n} \times C_2$. Then $H$ has an automorphism $\phi$ of order $2$ with $\phi(a) = a^{-1}c$ and $\phi(c)=c$. Let $\langle b \rangle$ with $b$ of order $4$ be cyclic, and let $X$ be the semidirect product $H \rtimes_\phi \langle b \rangle$. So $$X = \langle a,b,c \mid a^{2n}=b^4=c^2=1, ac=ca, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}c,b^{-1}cb=c \rangle,$$ and $|X| = 4|H| = 16n$.

Now $b^2, c \in Z(X)$, and we define $G = X/\langle b^2c^{-1} \rangle$, so $|G| = 8n$ and 
$$G = \langle a,b,c \mid a^{2n}=b^4=c^2=1, b^2=c, ac=ca, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}c,b^{-1}cb=c \rangle \cong \langle a,b\mid a^{2n}=b^4=1, ab^2=b^2a,  b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}b^2 \rangle.$$

Note that in $G$ we have $bab = b^2a^{-1}b^2 = a^{-1}$ (since $b^2 \in Z(G))$, and similarly $ba^{-1}b = a$, so the relations of $V_{8n}$ are indeed satisfied in $G$, and since $|G| = 8n$, this proves that $|V_{8n}| = 8n$ and $G \cong V_{8n}$.

Finally note that, in $G$, $b^2 = c \not\in \langle a \rangle$, which is what you wanted to prove.

Answer (score 3):

This answer uses [semidirect products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product). I hope you are familiar with them, else see the wikipedia link :-)

The following proves that if $b^2\in\langle a\rangle$ then $b^2=1$ (therefore it is an incomplete answer - but some of the working is applied in Derek Holt's answer, so I'll leave it here). One way to see this partial result is to quotient out $b^2$ from the group (that is, quotient out the normal subgroup generated by $b^2$, which I denote by $\langle\langle b^2\rangle\rangle$):
$$\begin{align*}
V_{8n}/\langle\langle b^2\rangle\rangle
&= \langle a, b  : a^{2n} = e, b^4 =e, ba = a^{-1}b^{-1}, b^{-1}a = a^{-1}b \rangle/\langle\langle b^2\rangle\rangle\\
&= \langle a, b  : a^{2n} = e, b^4 =e, ba = a^{-1}b^{-1}, b^{-1}a = a^{-1}b, b^2 \rangle\\
&= \langle a, b  : a^{2n} = e, b^2 =e, bab^{-1} = a^{-1}, bab^{-1} = a^{-1} \rangle\\
&= \langle a, b  : a^{2n} = e, b^2 =e, bab^{-1} = a^{-1}\rangle
\end{align*}
$$
This is a presentation for the semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2$. In particular, the image of $\langle a\rangle$ has order $2n$ in the quotient, and so $a$ has the same order both in $V_{8n}$ and in the quotient group. Therefore, the subgroup $\langle a\rangle$ intersects the kernel trivially, $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle\langle b^2\rangle\rangle=_{V_{8n}}1$, and hence if $b^2\in \langle a\rangle$ then $b^2=1$, as required.

Comment: But I think that to complete the proof you also need to prove that $b^2 \ne 1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah good point! From my rough skim of your answer, you just refer to this one and don't use is, so its fine if I delete mine?

Comment: Well I am using your proof that the $V_{8n}/\langle b^2\rangle$ is dihedral of order $4n$ so perhaps you should leave it!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers and comments.